# restoration identifier on storyboard in ios 5

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, identifier

I am making sample application of state preservation & restoration. I have read & did an demo on ios 6. In ios 6 I can set restoration identifier on storyboard for perticular viewController in the identity inspector.

below image is of ios6

[image]

But in ios 5 there is no such facility is available. that means there is no restoration identifier field in identity inspector of viewController. Then Now how i can set Restoration identifier on storyboard in ios5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inbuilt state preservation & restoration is only available in ios6 . This facility is not available in ios5. thats why there is no any restoration identifier available on ios5.